# ERROR Trying to connect to MySQL in STS using Spring Framework and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

[console output][1]
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79NJ.png
This is the error I get trying to connect to my database. Any ideas why?
I did some research, I went through the code several times and I still can't understand why it does not connect.

```
web.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>estore</display-name>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

dispatcher-servlet.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.estore"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>

applicationContext.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storeDB" />
        <property name="username" value="storeadm" />
        <property name="password" value="storeadm123" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.estore</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>

HomeController.java

        package com.estore.controllers;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import com.estore.dao.ProductDao;
    import com.estore.model.Product;


    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private ProductDao productDao;

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "home";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/productList")
        public String getProducts(Model model) {
            List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProducts();
            model.addAttribute("products", products);

            return "productList";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct/{productId}") //{} - path variable
        public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productId, Model model) throws IOException { // having @PathVariable to grab the variable "value" from path
                                                                                                    //then give the "value" to the "productId" String
            Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
            model.addAttribute(product);

            return "viewProduct";
        }
    }

ProductDao.java

    package com.estore.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.estore.model.Product;

public interface ProductDao {

    void addProduct(Product product);

    Product getProductById(String id);

    List<Product> getAllProducts();

    void deleteProduct(String id);

}

ProductDaoImpl

    package com.estore.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.estore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.estore.model.Product;


@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        Session session =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
        session.flush();
    }

    public Product getProductById(String id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Product product = (Product)session.get(Product.class, id);
        session.flush();

        return product;
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
        List<Product> products = query.list();

        session.flush();

        return products;
    }



    public void deleteProduct(String id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(getProductById(id));

        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have different versions of the log4j library in class path. Check (or post here) output of the `mvn dependency:tree` command. if you're creating WAR/JAR then inspect output of `jar tvf app.jar | grep '\.jar$'` command.

Comment: I solved the problem.

Comment: ...and what was the cause?